# How to write Fibonacci Java program without using if

Tags: java

What is the code to write in int Fibonacci (int n) without using "if" like they did here [Java recursive Fibonacci sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965006/java-recursive-fibonacci-sequence) ?
I tried to write this but it is wrong :
Because in this program the list will be 1 1 2 3 5 8 and not 0 1 1 2 3 5 8

Here is the program I tried to write:

```
public class Fibonacci
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int f = 0;
        int g = 1;

        for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            f = f + g;
            g = f - g;
            System.out.print(f + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is the program I tried to write : public class Fibonacci {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int f=0;
        int g=1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            f = f + g;
            g = f - g;
            System.out.print(f+" "); 
        }
        System.out.println();
     }
}

Comment: You can edit your post to add the code..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your program is entirely correct; all you need to change is the location of the print statement:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int f = 0;
  int g = 1;

  for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
  {
    System.out.print(f + " ");
    f = f + g;
    g = f - g;
  } 

  System.out.println();
}
```

Alternatively, print `g` instead of `f`.

Answer (score 11):

Pure formula for calculating Fibonacci number:

```
public double getFibonacci(int n) {
    double f1 = Math.pow(((1 + Math.sqrt(5)) / 2.0), n);
    double f2 = Math.pow(((1 - Math.sqrt(5)) / 2.0), n);

    return Math.floor((f1 - f2) / Math.sqrt(5));
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: +1 for letting me know a mathematical formula for this

Answer (score 4):

No if statements here:

```
public static void printFib(final int N) { 
    int f0 = 0; 
    int f1 = 1; 

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) { 
        System.out.println(f0);   
        final int temp = f1; 
        f1 += f0; 
        f0 = temp; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the one that I follow, its quite short and does without using `if`

```
    public class ShortFibboCode{

    public static void main(String a[]) {
        int f = 0;
        int numUpto = 10; // number of series upto - change accordingly
        for(int t = 1; f < numUpto; t = f + (f = t))
            System.out.print((f + " ");
        }
}
```

Comment: `t = f + (f = t)` makes my head hurt.

Comment: @Code-Guru its simply reducing the two statement/step process into one

Comment: @sanix Yes, I get it...after a little bit of effort.

Comment: @Code-Guru there you go real Code-Guru