# optimization for javascript recursive

Tags: javascript, recursion

So, I have this task:
Where n is a positive integer, the function f(n) satisfies the following

```
f(0) = 0 
f(1) = 1
f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2) when n > 1
```

1. Please create a program to find f(n)
2. Use the program to find f(8181)

   ```
   const f = (n) => {
     if(n === 0) {
       return 0
     } else if(n === 1) {
       return 1
     } else if(n > 1) {
       return f(n-1) + f(n-2)
     } else {
       return null
     }
   }
   ```

above is the code that i have wrote but it only do just fine when i do n < 40, it starts to slow down when n > 41. it takes forever to load f(100) let alone f(8181)
so, is there any way to optimized this code to meet all the requirements?
thank you in advance!

ps: it's not a school task so i dont have anyone to consult

Comment: For `n>2`, `f(n-1)` will involve calling `f(n-2)`, so you're doing twice as much work as needed for each iteration step. What should be an `O(n)` operation is becoming `O(2^n)`!!

Comment: i know right, but the requirement said i should do the recursion. so im wondering if i could write a condition or something

Comment: `const f = (src=>(n) => {while(src.length <= n) src[src.length] = src[src.length-1] + src[src.length-2]; return src[n];})([0,1]);` uses dynamic programming, not recursion - however, it is important to note that `f(79) > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` - for `n>=79` you will get approximate values. `f(8181)` returns `Infinity`.

Comment: [`f(8181)` is a 1,710-digit number](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibCalcX.html) - who assigned this insane task to you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fast Fibonacci recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13826810/fast-fibonacci-recursion)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Sounds like a job interview question, or in general a question which has the claim that one thinks more about the problem than to implement it only stupidly. Finding a fast algorithm to calculate this recursion is not such a big deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) to optimize the algorithm.

The idea is to remember the result of `f(n - 1) + f(n - 2)` in a JS object so that further calculations can use the memoized result instead of re-calculating everything.

Following is a demo, which instantly prints the result for `f(100)` correctly.

```js
let dict = {};

const f = (n) => {
  if (n === 0) {
    return 0
  } else if (n === 1) {
    return 1
  } else if (n > 1) {
    if (!dict[n]) {
      dict[n] = f(n - 1) + f(n - 2);
    }

    return dict[n];
  } else {
    return null
  }
}

console.log(f(100));
```

Comment: ah thank you!! it works. i even just heard that there is something like memoization principal lol

Comment: `f(100)` is `354 224 848 179 261 915 075`, which is rather different from the `354 224 848 179 262 000 000` your code gives ;)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol -- Did you really compare the values? :D I suppose this behaviour is due to limitations of JavaScript numbers. But the crux is memoization here. :)

Comment: I used the calculator I found and linked in a comment on the question :D And yeah. Floats are accurate to about 14-15 significant digits, which is only enough up to `f(78)`.

Comment: @ergxpr0xy -- please consider accepting this answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol ah sure sorry!

Answer (score 0):

@31piy - Avoid using recursion as it is not memory efficient also because each function is getting pushed in call-stack which slows down program. Here is the program for Fibonacci series till n number without recursion.

Hope this will help you :)

```
/**
 * Method to return Fibonacci series with linear (without recursion)
 * @param {*} n 
 */
function getFibonacciSeries(n){
    var n1 = 0, n2 = 1, a = [], n3;
    a.push(n1);
    a.push(n2);
    for(i=2; i < n; i++){
        n3 = n1 + n2;
        a.push(n3);
        n1 = n2;
        n2 = n3;
    }
    console.log(a);
    return a[n-1];
}
```

Comment: This is nice, but it re-builds the entire array each time you call the function. Far better to have a single static array that persists across function calls. Just extend the array if the new call is higher than any previous call.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - You are right, that is more optimized one.

Comment: FYI -- The solution I proposed doesn't recurse much. If it finds the value in the `dict` object, then no recursion takes place. So, I think, the entire call-stack limits to 2-3 frames (didn't evaluate yet though).