# Need to explain with Fibonacci

Tags: java, fibonacci

I have seen many examples of Fibonacci here on Stack Overflow but I have found no answer for my question. So, I have a code:

```
public class Fib {
    public static int fib(int n) {
        if (n < 2) {
           return n;
        }
        else {
   return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2);
        }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
        System.out.print(fib(i)+", ");
}
}
```

After run it we will get **0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13,**

I have a question: How do we get **8** ? fib(6)=............

Can anyone write in detail?

Comment: Trace out what happens if you run `fib(6)` yourself on a piece of paper and you can see what is going to happen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java recursive Fibonacci sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965006/java-recursive-fibonacci-sequence). This question already pretty explained, here

Comment: Should be closed as doesn't show a minimum understanding of the problem (just glance at comments on answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fib(6) = fib(5)+fib(4) = fib(4)+fib(3)+fib(3)+fib(2) = fib(3)+fib(2)+fib(2)+fib(1)+fib(2)+fib(1)+fib(1)+fib(0) = fib(2)+fib(1)+fib(1)+fib(0)+fib(1)+fib(0)+1+fib(1)+fib(0)+1+1+0 = fib(1)+fib(0)+1+1+0+1+0+1+1+0+1+1+0 = 1+0+1+1+0+1+0+1+1+0+1+1+0=8
```

Hope it helped..

Answer (score 1):

```
fib(0) = 0
fib(1) = 1
fib(2) = fib(1) + fib(0) = 1
fib(3) = fib(2) + fib(1) = 2
fib(4) = fib(3) + fib(2) = 3
fib(5) = fib(4) + fib(3) = 5
fib(6) = fib(5) + fib(4) = 8
```

When you call `fib(6)` it will execute `fib(5)` and `fib(4)` etc. until it hits the base cases `fib(1)` and `fib(0)`.

Comment: Can you write more detail this fib(6) = fib(5) + fib(4) = .........................................................=8

Comment: @Sven.. all other details in same answer. Now yourself try it out to find out for other :)

Comment: @Sven Start with `fib(6)=fib(5)+fib(4)` and substitute `fib(5)` and `fib(4)`, and keep on substituting until you're only left with constants. Here's the first step: `fib(6)=fib(5)+fib(4)=fib(4)+2*fib(3)+fib(2)=...`

Comment: I mean like this fib(3) = fib(2) + fib(1) //so we we are into the else statement, because 3 > 1
= fib(2) + 1             //fib(1) = 1 because 1 <= 1 so you return it (if statement)
= (fib(1) + fib(0)) + 1  //2 > 1 => we go to the else statement
= (1 + 0) + 1            //0 <= 1 & 1 <= 1 so we are into the if and return the values 
= 2

Comment: Just remember that `fib(n+1)=fib(n)+fib(n-1)`, with initial conditions `fib(1)=1, fib(0)=0`. Now you code this however you want but whenever you encounter either conditions above, you return the corresponding value.

Answer (score 0):

```
fib(6) = fib(5) + fib(4)  //..
fib(5) = fib(4) + fib(3)  //..
fib(4) = fib(3) + fib(2)  //2 + 1 
fib(3) = fib(2) + fib(1)  //1 + 1
fib(2) = fib(1) + fib(0)  //1 + 0  Begin here (stop condition)
```

Comment: Can you write more detail this fib(6) = fib(5) + fib(4) = .........................................................=8

Comment: That's all details you need. Think.

Comment: i mean like this fib(3) = fib(2) + fib(1)= fib(2) + 1 = (fib(1) + fib(0)) + 1 = (1 + 0) + 1 = 2

Comment: Well.. it's exactly the same.. Just put some line into other.