# F# Understanding the Fibbonacci Sequence Recursively

Tags: math, recursion, f#, fibonacci

This might sound like a School assignment but it is not!

I have made a recursive function returning a value from the Fibonacci Sequence.

```
let rec FoneFive n =
    match n with
    | 1 | 2 -> 1
    | n -> FoneFive(n-1) + FoneFive(n-2)

printfn "%A" (FoneFive 6)
```

What is going on in this recursive function? `FoneFive 6` gives 8 as it should. But why?

The way I see it: It starts with n=6 and concludes that 6 is not 1 or 2. So it calls `FoneFive(n-1) + FoneFive(n-2)`. (This is probably where I get it wrong. But the way I see it is that this return nothing unless n is 1 or 2. So from my point of view it will narrow both down n = 1 or 2 and there by say 1 + 1 which of course is 2.)

Can someone tell me how it returns 8 ?

Comment: Please see the Java recursive answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/8965075/509840. F# works exactly the same way.

Comment: You're on the right track when you say it calls `FoneFive(n-1) + FoneFive(n-2)`.  That means the call with `n=6` makes calls with `n=5` and `n=4`, which in turn make calls with smaller `n`, until you get to calls with 1 or 2 and can return an actual value.  Track it through by hand, or with a debugger, to see how you get to 8.

Comment: Imagine `n` was 3. Then you'd return `FoneFive(n-1) + FoneFive(n-2)` = `FoneFive(2) + FoneFive(1)` = `1 + 1` = 2. So you can see that `FoneFive(3)` returns 2. That contradicts your last statement, so hopefully gives you the intuition to see why other values greater than `n=3` work too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calculating `FoneFive(6)` requires to calculate `FoneFive(5)` and `FoneFive(4)`
(as `5` and `4` are `n-1` and `n-2` for `n=6`)

Calculating `FoneFive(5)` requires to calculate `FoneFive(4)` and `FoneFive(3)`
(as `4` and `3` are `n-1` and `n-2` for `n=5`)

Calculating `FoneFive(4)` requires to calculate `FoneFive(3)` and `FoneFive(2)`
(as `3` and `2` are `n-1` and `n-2` for `n=4`)

Calculating `FoneFive(3)` requires to calculate `FoneFive(2)` and `FoneFive(1)`
(as `2` and `1` are `n-1` and `n-2` for `n=3`)

Both `FoneFive(1)` and `FoneFive(2)` returns `1`
so `FoneFive(3) = FoneFive(2) + FoneFive(1) = 1 + 1 = 2`
so `FoneFive(4) = FoneFive(3) + FoneFive(2) = 2 + 1 = 3`
so `FoneFive(5) = FoneFive(4) + FoneFive(3) = 3 + 2 = 5`
so `FoneFive(6) = FoneFive(5) + FoneFive(4) = 5 + 3 = 8`

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i get it now. It so to speak splits it selv up into two pieces every time n is not 1 or 2 and then again splits itself of to two pieces if that isn't 1 or 2 either.

```
f6 = f5 + f4
f5 + f4 = f4 + f3 + f3 + (f2=1)
f4 + f3 + f3 + (f2=1) = f3 + (f2=1) + (f2=1) + (f1=1) + (f2=1) + (f1=1) + 1
f3 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = (f2=1) + (f1=1) + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
(f2=1) + (f1=1) + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 8
```

Comment: why didn't you just accepted the answer @Sehnsucht?

Comment: Not quite following ya ?

Comment: what you mean ?