# find the sum of all the numbers in the Fibonacci series that are smaller or equal to that number

Tags: java, numbers, sum, fibonacci

The Fibonacci numbers are the numbers in the following integer sequence.

```
0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144 . . .
```

Given a specific number in this series Fn, your program needs to find the sum of all the numbers in the Fibonacci series that are smaller or equal to that number.

Input Format
Your program will be provided a number in the Fibonacci series on STDIN.

Constraints

```
0<<Fn<100000
```

Sample Input

```
8
```

Sample Output

```
The output for above input (8) should be 0 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 5 + 8
20
```

To solve above problem I write a code like

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class MyTest{
    public static Integer solveProblem(int n) {
        if (n>=0 || n<100000) {
        int fibo[] = new int[n+1];
        fibo[0] = 0; fibo[1] = 1;
        int sum = fibo[0] + fibo[1];
        for (int i=2; i<=n; i++) {
            fibo[i] = fibo[i-1]+fibo[i-2];
            if(n >= fibo[i]) {
                sum += fibo[i];
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        return sum;
        } else {
            return 0;    
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sum = MyTest.solveProblem(in.nextInt());
        System.out.println("This is the output:"+sum);
    }
}
```

I run the program it works fine with the sample test case as mentioned but when I submit this program on online test quiz then it run with their test case and it will fail.

Is something wrong in my program or I didn't understand the question properly. Please help me to find out exact answer of this problem.

Comment: Well, you don't use the scanner to get the value, you set "8" in parameter.

Comment: Also this condition is always true: `if (n>=0 || n<100000)`

Comment: I changed and read input from scanner but still not accpeting

Comment: It's hard to tell since you are not providing an example test case that fails.

Comment: I dont know those test cases, they run their test cases but not showing to me what input they are tested

Comment: Well, you could try to fix the constraint that I pointed out and try again.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965006/java-recursive-fibonacci-sequence - usually solved through recursion

Comment: If you try with `n=0`, you get an array of `int[1]` then try to access `array[1]` -> exception

Comment: Hmm, should not the result be `21` ?

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number the eight element is `21` `20` does not appear

Comment: @ScaryWombat, read again, it is doing the sum of every fibonnaci numbers smaller or equals to the input, not getting that specific value ;-) so `1+1+2+3+5+8 = 20`

Comment: @AxelH *read again* - Sorry, yes I should.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I do that a lot, so I understand ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems to fail for n=0 and n=1.

- For n=1 you return 1 but should return 2 (since there are two elements whose value is 1, and you should be adding both of them to the sum).
- For n=0 you are throwing an exception.

You could fix this by adding a special check for these cases:

```
public static Integer solveProblem(int n) {
    if (n==0) 
        return 0;
    else if (n==1) 
        return 2;
    else if (n>=0 || n<100000) {
        int fibo[] = new int[n+1];
        fibo[0] = 0; fibo[1] = 1;
        int sum = fibo[0] + fibo[1];
        for (int i=2; i<=n; i++) {
            fibo[i] = fibo[i-1]+fibo[i-2];
            if(n >= fibo[i]) {
                sum += fibo[i];
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        return sum;
    } else {
        return 0;    
    }
}
```

Comment: How yeah, didn't notice the problem with `n = 1` ! Nice catch.

Answer (score 1):

You should get the value from the Scanner

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int sum = MyTest.solveProblem(8);
```

by using `Scanner.nextInt()`

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int sum = MyTest.solveProblem(in.nextInt());
```

---

If you input a value of `0`, it is accepted by your condition but you create an array of size 1, then try to access the second value -> `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

```
int fibo[] = new int[n+1];
fibo[0] = 0; 
fibo[1] = 1; //HERE, exception as there is not `fibo[1]`
```

Update the condition to

```
if ( n > 0 && n < 100000) //note the && to correct your logic error too
```

NOTE : I don't think this is a good idea to use an array here since you are using a big array that is not necessary (not fully used), using two variables (last, current) would be simpler.

Comment: Hey, I changed and read the input using scanner but still not accpeting

Comment: To the downvoters, please note that OP have edited his question as this was a first problem ... I will add the rest of the solution once we have it!

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class CutShort
{
    public static long solveProblem(int input) {        

        long sum = 0;        

        long finalstate = 1;
        long currentstate = 0;

        while(finalstate<=input) {

            sum = sum+finalstate;

            long add = currentstate + finalstate;

            currentstate = finalstate;

            finalstate = add;
        }
        return sum;

    }


public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception

    {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        /*Parse input here*/

        System.out.println("Enter you Input");

        int input = in.nextInt();

        long output = 0;

        if(input>0 && input<100000)

        output = solveProblem(input);

        System.out.println("This is the output" + output);

    }

}
```