# Debugging my recursive Fibonacci Java code and correcting the logic

Tags: java, debugging, recursion, fibonacci

I'm unable to understand why the output is wrong.

I've tried to write a recursive code of printing Fibonacci numbers and got the expected output and a stream of unexpected values.

```
public class FibonacciSeries {

    static int limitNum = 10;  //the desired number of Fibonacci values

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FibonacciSeries series = new FibonacciSeries();
        series.printRecursiveFibonacci(0,1,1);
    }

    public void printRecursiveFibonacci(int a, int b, int count)
    {
        while(count<=limitNum)
        {
          if(count==1||count==2)
          {
            System.out.println(count-1);
            count++;
            continue;
          }

        int k=a+b;
        a=b;
        b=k;
        System.out.println(b);
        count++;
        printRecursiveFibonacci(a, b, count);   
        }
    }

}
```

The expected output is 
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34

But I got - 
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
34
21
34
34
13
21
34
34
21
34
34
8
13
21
34
34
21
34
34
13
21
34
34
21
34
34
5
8
13
21
34
34
21
34
34
13
21
34
34
21
34
34
8
13
21
34
34
21
34
34
13
21
34
34
21
34
34
3
5
8
13
21
34
34
21
34
34
13
21
34
34
21
34
34
8
13
21
34
34
21
34
34
13
21
34
34
21
34
34
5
8
13
21
34
34
21
34
34
13
21
34
34
21
34
34
8
13
21
34
34
21
34
34
13
21
34
34
21
34
34
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
34
21
34
34
13
21
34
34
21
34
34
8
13
21
34
34
21
34
34
13
21
...

Comment: What's the purpose of your `while(count<=limitNum)` loop in your recursive function? That loop is occurring on every recursive call which doesn't make much sense. If you're using recursion, you don't need a loop.

Comment: "*Please help me in understand the output of this recursive Fibonacci java code ...*" --- Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) --- "*... and correct the logic*" - How is that supposed to help? If we solve it for you, we take away every chance for you learning something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java recursive Fibonacci sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965006/java-recursive-fibonacci-sequence)

Comment: @lurker, Thank you very much for pointing that out. I was practicing recursion and got lost. after replacing the while with if, it worked. Thank you again, I learnt my lesson.

Comment: @Turing85, I knew there is a mistake in my code and tried seeking help here to identity it as I was lost with it. Now, because of you, I learnt a better way to phrase my question and thanks a lot to your suggestion, really appreciate it. and I also spotted the mistake in my code.

Comment: @ButiriDan I'm afraid not and nonetheless, I got the answer. Thank you anyway, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have mixed 3 (!) different tasks within a single method:

1. Calculation of the next Fibonacci number
2. Printing Fibonacci number
3. Limiting the number of Fibonacci numbers you are going to find

There is a good principle: separation of concerns. Each method should perform exactly *one* task.

Besides, if you refer recusrsion, probably you meant following:

```
fibonacci(n) = fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
```

Split your method:

1. In one method keep only calculation the next Fibonacci number.
2. In another method organize a loop and printing.

Here is a possible solution:

```
public class Fibonacci {

    private static final int LIMIT = 10;

    private static int fibonacci(int n) {
        if (n == 1) {
            // The 1st Fibonacci number is 0
            return 0;
        }

        if (n == 2) {
            // The 2nd Fibonacci number is 1
            return 1;
        }

        return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= LIMIT; i++) {
            int fibo = fibonacci(i);
            System.out.println(fibo);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for suggesting the design pattern. I was trying to practice recursion and got lost with the code.

Comment: See above with recursion.

Comment: @mentalurg, Thank you, I got it right after replacing the Loop with If condition. I learnt a lot from your answer. Thank you for helping this newbie, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what exactly is going on in your code, a lot of weird things are going on:

- `while` and recursion in the same method
- `if` and `continue` instead of `if/else`
- printing `count - 1` sometimes and `b` other times.

I suspect it has something to do with your loop not terminating as you expect. In general, try to stick to either recursion **or** loops. Here is an example implementation:

```
public static void printFibLimit(int a, int b, int count) {
    if (count >= EXTERNALLY_DEFINED_LIMIT_VARIABLE) return;  // if true, we're done, no more work has to be done. 
// Since this is a tail-recursive function, return will terminate the function

    System.out.println(a);  // print our first value

    printFibLimit(b, a + b, count + 1);
    // a -> b
    // b -> a + b
    // count -> count + 1

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I got it right now after replacing the Loop with If condition. I learnt a lot from your answer. Thank you for helping this newbie, really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)